# Rails 5 with JQuery: Form with show and hide JQuery toggle will show initially, but hide like it should after I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a post link that will show you comments and allow you to click a div to show you a comment form and likewise, hide the form if you click cancel.

When you follow the link from a post, the comment form starts in the open position, which I don't want.

However, if I simply refresh the page, it'll re-load the view with the comment form in the hide position. My JQuery skills are weak and I can't seem to figure out why it'll work on a page reload, but wont work when coming from another link.

Here is my comment form:

```
# shared/_comment_form
<div id="comment-form" class="form-group">
  <%= form_for @comment, remote: true, url: post_comments_path(@post) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, required: true, rows: 5, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_id, :value => @post.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_type, :value => @post.class.name %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<span id="add-comment">Add a comment</span>
```

Here is my js.erb file for my commentform

```
# comment_form.js.erb
$('#comment-form').hide().after('<%= j render("comment_form") %>');
```

My JQuery that will toggle the form open and shut.

```
# app/assets/application.js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#comment-form").hide();
  $('#add-comment').click( function() {
    $("#comment-form").fadeToggle("fast");
    ($("#add-comment").text() === "Cancel") ? $("#add-comment").text("Add comment") : $("#add-comment").text("Cancel");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using css as well?

```
#comment-form {
  display: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You mean `display: none;`? I could try that. I was trying to see if it could be fixed with JQuery.

Comment: I tried using `display:none` and set it to `.hidden` class.

I then used `.removeClass` on `.hidden` on click. 

It now wont show when coming from another page even if I click. However, if I refresh the page in place it then functions as it should. So that solution didn't quite get me there.